# Get number of rows with values less than current row's value

Tags: mysql

My mysql table is:

```
Id  | value | count_of_past_lower_values
1   | 120    |  0
2   | 210    | 1
3   |150     | 1
4   |140     | 1
5   |200     | 3
```

Given id and values, I have to update 3rd col. I made a query using `SUM(IF(value<X,1,0))` but not able to identify right expression for X.

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issuing a self-left-join with conditional sum would suffice:

```
select 
  a.id, 
  a.value, 
  sum(case when a.value > b.value then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_past_lower_values
from yourtable a
left join yourtable b on a.id > b.id
group by a.id, a.value
order by a.id
```

Result

```
 id | value | count_of_past_lower_values
----+-------+----------------------------
  1 |   120 |                          0
  2 |   210 |                          1
  3 |   150 |                          1
  4 |   140 |                          1
  5 |   200 |                          3
```